# Facing issue related to Date in Angular2

Tags: angular, datetime

From database data coming like this:

```
2017.08.14 11:48:24
```

I want the Date format like this,but in String only.

```
Mon Aug 14 2017 11:48:24 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

How to do it in Typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const date: Date = new Date('2017.08.14 11:48:24');
const dateStr: string = date.toString();
```

That should work

Comment: yeh!! Dude..working fine.I just forget about toString(). Working fine.Thanks.